# How can I fix 'Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Int' in this for loop

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop

After hours of trying to find an answer, I'm officially stumped.

I have an array of strings:

```
let artists = ["Robben Ford", "Joe Bonamassa", "Eric Clapton", "Matt Schofield"]
```

Now I want to iterate over that array like this:

```
func refresh() {
    for artist in artists {
       let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: artist, inSection: 0) <---- Error
       if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
          cell.textLabel?.text = artist
      }
}
```

Xcode complains at the let indexPath statement, 'Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Int'. I understand that it expects forItem to be an Int but I can't figure out how to make it one.

I did try changing the for loop to

```
for artist in artists.enumerate() {
     }
```

but then it just says it can't covert '(index: Int, element: String)'.

The fix must be obvious to a non-beginner but it's not obvious to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just as an FYI. Your `refresh()` is not the way to update cells. You need to implement the UITableViewDataSource required methods. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/

Comment: Hi Daniel, I'm working with a tutorial about Accessory Views that implements this refresh method to ensure the rows are updated with a checkmark as the user selects different ones. I removed that part of the code in my post to simplify my example. I am implementing the three required methods for creating the tableView cells as well. Thanks for the comment though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for a beginner is simply :

```
for artist in artists.enumerate() {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: artist.index, inSection: 0)
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = artist.element
    }
}
```

The problem is that, you're trying to pass an "artist" `String` to the `forItem` parameter of the `NSIndexPath(forItem: Int, inSection: Int)` initializer. As you can see it requires 2 `Int` parameters. So @Ahaubster answer is correct, you just simply missed his last phrase.

Comment: Sorry, I made a little mistake there. Should compile now.

Comment: You still missed `element` but I fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

It does not work because you are passing in a string, not the index of a string. Try

```
for (index, artist) in artists.enumerate()
```

then pass in the index.

Comment: I love this syntax. It's the convenience of a `for in` loop with the functionality of `for` loop over a range of indices.